# Administrator exclusive page?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, login-control

I'm currently making a windows form login system and I've worked out how to set up a general everyone can see the main page system but for the admin i want it to open a new form (form3) which will contain customer orders.
i need it to open up from Login Button.Click just like form2 opens to show the store page for generalised users. i don't have a column in my table for user roles either.
I've tried if else statements and run into issues with bools not excepting strings etc.

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using MySql.Data;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

    namespace Aliena_Store
    {


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //string ConnectionState = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;database=Aliena_Store;port=3306;password=Blackie");
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    private void UsernameLogin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void PasswordLogin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `User_Details` WHERE `username` = '" + UsernameLogin.Text + "' AND `password` = '" + PasswordLogin.Text + "'", connection);

        adapter.Fill(table);
        var usernameSaved = UsernameLogin.Text;
        var passwordSaved = PasswordLogin.Text;
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();


        if (table.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {

         panel1.Height = 0;

         var result = MessageBox.Show("Username/Password Are Invalid or does not exist. Please sign up or retry your details");

        }

        else
        {
            panel1.Height = 0;
            this.Hide();
            if (table.Rows.Count >= 0)
            {

                Form nextForm;
                var result = MessageBox.Show("Login successful...Now logging in");
                this.Hide();
                object user = UsernameLogin.Text;
                object password = PasswordLogin.Text;
                if (user = "root" & password = "Pa$$w0rd")
                {
                    nextForm = new Form3();
                }
                else
                {
                    nextForm = new Form2();
                }
                nextForm.ShowDialog();
            }

            //Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            //f2.ShowDialog();

            //if login is successful needs to lead to another screen - if matches my account standard store screen or make root account just for the admin page
        }

        table.Clear();
    }


    private void EmailSignUp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void UsernameSignUp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void PasswordSignUp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SignUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //connection.Open();
        string Query = "insert into User_Details (Email,Username,Password) values('" + this.EmailSignUp.Text + "', '" + this.UsernameSignUp.Text + "','" + this.PasswordSignUp.Text + "');";
        //string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO User_Details(Email,Username,Password)VALUES('" + EmailSignUp.Text + "','" + UsernameSignUp.Text + "'," + PasswordSignUp.Text + ")";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query,connection);

        try
        {
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
                connection.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Not Inserted");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: _"ive tried a few ways to no success and currently cant get it up and running"_ is not a problem description. **What** did you try? *What* was the problem? Don't expect readers to be psychic or to waste their time suggesting things you already disproved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

You need a User object in your application that stores user properties.  This object can have an IsAdmin property that you can use later in your code.

Alternately, if you don't want to create and maintain a User object, you make another call to the database to see whether or not the user is an admin and store the result local to your method.

You then instantiate `Form3` instead of `Form2` based on whether or not the user is an admin.

```
Form nextForm;
var result = MessageBox.Show("Login successful...Now logging in");
this.Hide();
if (user.IsAdmin) {
    nextForm = new Form3();
} else {
    nextForm = new Form2();
}
nextForm.ShowDialog();
```

PS: I hope you are not storing passwords in plain text in your database like it seems you are.

Comment: im storing passwords as its university work and the teacher just wants to see certain functionality, he isnt fussed in this current scenario about  security since all the info is randomly generated prior to input and given in as auto inserted data.

Comment: @Dusky Ok, fair enough.  Always prudent to point out, though.

Comment: got it to this point but then i get a standard error: operater && cannot be applied between string and object. anyway to bypass that with something similar to this: panel1.Height = 0;
                this.Hide();
                if (table.Rows.Count >= 0)
                {
Form nextForm;
var result = MessageBox.Show("Login successful...Now logging in");                                                                                  
this.Hide();
object user = UsernameLogin.Text;
object password = PasswordLogin.Text;
if (user = "root" & password = "Pa$$w0rd"

Comment: Why are you checking username and password again after login?  Edit your new code into your question (all of it).  The code you pasted doesn't even include the `&&` operator.

Comment: im not..i dont think i am anyway - i updated it so if its not valid it goes first and then it should go through as valid or valid admin..

Comment: Your `if` statement syntax is wrong.  You're using the `=` assignment operator instead of the `==` comparison operator, and you're using the `&` bitwise AND operator instead of the `&&` logical AND operator.  It should be `if (user == "root" && password == "Pa$$w0rd")`.  Fix that and I think you should be in business.